# how to use play format serialization/deserialization macro for nested case objects

Tags: scala, playframework

So I have a sealed trait like such:

```
sealed trait Foo {

  override def toString: String = {
    ...
  }
}
```

and a companion object like:

```
object Foo {

  case object Bar extends Foo {}

  case object Bat extends Foo {}

  case object Bah extends Foo {}


  def parse(s: String): Foo = {

    ...
  }

  implicit val format: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]

  def apply(f: String): Foo = parse(f)

  def unapply(f: Foo): String = f.toString

}
```

I would have expected the macro to work since it meets all of the requirements stated here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Requirements

However, I get a compile time error that states that there are no subclasses for Foo (even though there are Bar, Bat and Bah) .

If I move Bar, Bat and Bah outside of Foo (to the base package level), the complaint goes away.

Just wondering if this is an oversight in the macro (where is cannot find nested subclasses), or if I am doing something incorrect here?

Comment: That's a macro edge case. You try to define the macro in the not yet fully ended scope where it should look of the trait subtypes: compiler just doesn't yet know at this point.